# M + N log N running time for Dijkstra

Tags: data-structures, shortest-path, heaps, dijkstras-algorithm

I'm taking the Design and Algorithms Part -II course in Coursera by professor Tim Roughgarden. In one of the classes, he mentioned that the running time for Dijkstra is $O(m \log n )$ using the heap data structure where $m$ is the number of edges and $n$ is the number of vertices. Also, he mentioned that using an exotic type of heap data structure the running time can be improved to $O(m + n \log n)$. I googled and couldn't find any relevant answers. It would be much helpful to know such data structures as its running time would be blazingly fast. Can anybody help?

Comment: Maybe he meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap ?

Comment: As @nirshahar has stated, Fibonacci heaps are a way to improve the time complexity. however, as stated in the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap#Worst_case), they are not "blazingly fast", only asymptotically faster (and difficult to implement).

Comment: @nirshahar . Seems like it. because the article says the fibonacci heap's worst case time complexity is O(a + b log n) where a = number of inserts, b = number of deletions, n = max size of heap. Here we would be inserting *m* number of edges into the heap and would do a deletion during each iteration which sums to n number of deletions and max size is the number of heap. In our case the maximum size is m - the number of edges. The last part is the only place where it seems different. By the definition it becomes O(M + N Log M). Anyway thanks. Will check whether modifications can be done.

Comment: @nirshahar I think the as there could be a maximum of quadratic number of edges in graphs corresponding to the number vertices. Thus m=n^2. Thus applying this in the time complexity found  reduces O(M + N log M) => O(M + N Log N ^ 2) => O(M + 2 * N Log N) => O(M + N log N).

Comment: @Nathaniel thanks for information. Does Dijkstra's shortest path practically run faster in Fibonacci heap than using binary heap or is it slower ? How do they differ in Sparse and Dense graph. you have any suggestion ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: @VeeraKumar My experience is that Dijkstra's all shortest paths runs measurably much faster using a Fibonacci heap on the large (~1 billion node) sparse (<= 4 output edges per node) graphs that I needed to run it on. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @D.W. thanks :)

Comment: @Pseudonym Thanks. That helped a lot. I need to compute All pair Shortest Path using johnson's algorithm (which in turn uses Dijkstra). And i need a faster method than normal PriorityQueue or Binary Heap. My graph contains 20000 Nodes and running via Fibonacci heap would be good it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @nirshahar for pointing out the data structure is Fibonacci heap with a worst case running time of *O(a + b log n)* where a = number of inserts, b = number of deletions, n = maximum size of the heap. For Dijkstra's algorithm for shortest path we have to insert M number of edges initially followed by n number of deletions in each iteration. Hence it worst case is *O(m + n log m)*. In worst case for a dense graph m = n^2. Thus the worst case running time is transformed to O(m + n log n).